# My button background seems stretched

Tags: css, button, background-image, stretch

I have a button as made for you to see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6CDDh/5/). Looks fine,right? Well on the live site, [euroworker.no/shipping](http://euroworker.no/checkout/shipping) and [/selectAddress](http://euroworker.no/checkout/selectAddress) it seems stretched.

Renders fine in Chrome, IE and Safari, I thought it might have been a FF issue, but loaded the fiddle into FF and seems fine.

Quick ref CSS and html:

```
#fortsett_btn  {
   background-image: url(http://euroworker.no/public/upload/fortsett.png?1269434047);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:left;
   background-color:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
   visibility: visible;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   width: 106px;
   height: 25px;
   cursor:pointer;
}​
```

And HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" id="fortsett_btn" title="Fortsett" value="">&nbsp;</button>​
```

I wonder what's up with it.

Comment: The button doesn't even render, I just get a normal OS button (Firefox 3.6.2 and IE 7, Windows XP.)  In IE I get a couple of Javascript errors which might explain it.  Your jQuery file is giving a 404 - http://euroworker.no/public/jquery.min.js

Comment: I am not seeing any styling on the button on the live page. Looks like the style sheet is not being loaded at all?

Comment: I dont see the IMG on the live site, just a standard <button> with no styling.

Comment: I'm getting a doc type error, and I see the normal OS buttons as well

Comment: Yeah I need to get rid of that JS, thanks. Weird it's not loading the CSS file. It's being loaded fine here on about 6 computers in my office..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" id="fortsett_btn" title="Fortsett" value="">&nbsp;</button>
```

Try this :

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" id="fortsett_btn" title="Fortsett" value="">Some value</button>
```

then add `text-indent:-999px;` to your CSS

This has nothing to do why your button is unaffected on live site, its just suggestion. You button doesn't style probably because you're missing a style sheet(wrong link), try styling it inline, then if it works copy  the style to the style sheet

Comment: Thanks, will add this to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. The CSS is different in each case. On Fiddle you have a single image with a background-repeat set to no-repeat. On the live site you have a slice of a different image with background-repeat set to repeat-x. Those are two different ways of styling the button.

Fiddle:

```
#fortsett_btn {
background-image:url("http://euroworker.no/public/upload/fortsett.png?1269434047");
background-position:left center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:medium none;
cursor:pointer;
height:25px;
position:relative;
visibility:visible;
width:106px;
z-index:2;
}
```

Live:

```
#product___specField_8  {
-moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
background-image:url("stylesheet/frontend/../../upload/orng_bg.png?1269434608");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
float:left;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
height:33px;
padding-left:55px;
width:124px;
}
```

Why wouldn't you expect to see something different?

Comment: @Robusto Indeed a dark secret that only fire-bug can tell :D

Comment: Those are two different IDs. 

1: #fortsett_btn, my button.

2: #product__specfield_8, my customised input field.

:)

Comment: @Kyle: I just examined the "orange" button on each page. The one on the second page was longer (i.e., "stretched") so I assumed that's what you were talking about. The fact that they were different IDs doesn't necessarily mean anything because one was a sandbox with simplified sample code and the other was live.

Comment: I understand what you were aiming at, just you got some ids confused, they're both calling the same ID; fortsett_btn.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks `they're both calling the same ID` , you mustn't let that happen, ID are unique per document, you can use same class on multiple elements

Comment: I realise this, but didn't know it also applied to the same element on two different pages, thanks.